# AWS Load Balancer Https Listening to EC2 on http

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, https

I have my website running in an EC2 instance, Apache2 listening on 80.

Since, it should be using https, I configured a AWS Load Balancer . Added ACM certificate to the Load Balancer.

Added the Load Balancer's dns in Domain's alias in Route53.

And Load balancer listening to 443 and redirecting to EC2 instance's 80.

Configured EC2 security group to only accept connections from the ELB's security group on port 80.

Now the issue is, when I access my website, it shows content without js and css.

Saying, "This page trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources".

Those scripts and stylesheets are in the EC2 instance.

What is the right way, to make all scripts, stylesheets, images loaded through https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an app issue not a server issue if you want the ELB to terminate SSL.

It terminated ssl on the ELB and passes back http to the webserver. So your app is seeing normal http traffic. The ELB adds a special header to the traffic to let anything behind it know that the traffic was SSL in case it wants to send back things like return links/js/css/images with https://

It sends the following header back

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto

Your app must be smart enough to say ok the schema is https OR this header is set so its ssl.. if not http.

Comment: Thanks. This means, I need configure Apache to listen on 443?

Comment: You can do that sure and use your own cert or fix your app to honor the http header for ssl termination